# Objective C subtraction

Tags: objective-c, subtraction

When I do this:

```
NSLog(@"%i",1.5 - 1.00 == 0.5);
```

I get 1, but when I do this:

```
NSLog(@"%i",1.33 - 1.00 == 0.33);
```

I get 0.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Every programmer should understand floating point numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers In short, 1.33 - 1.00 is not 0.33.

Comment: How many dupes of (variations of) this question have been asked on SO... no effort to use Google... Eh...

Comment: @H2CO3 The problem is that it is hard to explain to Google what you are looking for, unless you know to ask for floating-point precision or something related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the precision of floating-point calculations: you should generally avoid comparing floats and double-precision numbers for equality using `==` operator, preferring a check for the difference to be smaller than a tiny *epsilon* (e.g. `1E-9`).

```
#include <math.h>

...

NSLog(@"%i", abs(((1.33 - 1.00) - 0.33) < 1E-9);
```

The first example works because the numbers are composed of powers of 2: `1 = 2^0`, and `0.5 = 2^-1`.  The numbers from the second example cannot be decomposed as powers of 2 exactly, so the equality check does not work.